# How to calculate the power required by a fountain pump?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, power, flow, efficient-energy-use

How can I calculate the power required by a fountain pump, if just the efficiency of the pump, the height of the fountain and the diameter of the water jet is given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the height of the fountain stream tells you how fast the water needs to be moving when it exits the pump discharge pipe so as to reach that height at the top of its trajectory. the speed of the water times the pipe diameter times the density tells you what the mass flow rate of water through the system is. the mass flow rate times the fountain height tells you what the fluid horsepower requirement is. the fluid horsepower divided by the pump efficiency tells you the power rating of the electric motor you will need.

Comment: To get the velocity I'll have to use the formula v= square root of(2*g*h), right?

Comment: i think that's right. it's the same equation you use for predicting the maximum height of a thrown ball.